# mediaelementplayer play from specific position

Tags: mediaelement.js

How can I play this player from specific position. 
Actually I have the number of seconds played and I need to start playing video from the position specified by this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
mediaElement.setCurrentTime(10);
```

where mediaElement is the video instance.

I used this in the following code to make the video jump back to a timecode once it reached a specified time:

```
$('#video').mediaelementplayer({
    success: function (mediaElement) {                      
        mediaElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(e) {
            //console.log(mediaElement.currentTime)                                         
            if(mediaElement.currentTime > 80 ) mediaElement.setCurrentTime(10);                 
        }, false);                  
     }
 });
```